# Visual Studio does not build with "Unable to copy file. Access denied."

Tags: visual-studio

I have a project on GitHub. I cloned it in my visual studio in another pc. After hitting build it shows this error.

> Unable to copy file "G:\Shikkhanobish\ShikkhanobishApp\Shikkhanobish\Shikkhanobish\bin\Debug\netstandard2.1\Shikkhanobish.dll" to "C:\Users\Microsoft\Desktop\Shikkhanobish.dll".
>
> Access to the path 'C:\Users\Microsoft\Desktop' is denied.

I tried to change output path but didn't work. This ***"C:\Users\Microsoft\Desktop"*** is that location from where I pushed the project on GitHub. I don't know why it is copying output path.

Comment: it seems that you have problems with visual studio but not git or github, ca you try to run your visual studio as administrator and tell if the error still occurs?

Answer (score 0):

If you run IT As An Administrator, it should work. You do it by following these steps:

- Click the start button
- Type "Visual Studio"
- Right click on the result (the app)
- Choose "Run As Administrator"

P.S: If you meant to do it on your Desktop, the path would be: `C:\Users\<YourAccount>\Desktop`
and not "Microsoft" like you show in your Q.